# Dynamically create instance of a form and show it

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created a dictionary:

```
Public DicForms As New Dictionary(Of String, Form)
DicForms.Add("FrmAbout", FrmAbout)
DicForms.Add("FrmAddAcGroup", FrmAddAcGroup)
'..
'..
'upto 71 items
```

Following is my module function to show a form inside MDIParent:

```
Public Sub OpenForm(ByVal frm As Form)
    With frm
        .MdiParent = FrmMain
        .Show()
        .Focus()
    End With
End Sub
```

And I'm trying to open a Form that available in dictionary `DicForms`:

```
'FormName = "FrmAbout"
If Not formName Is Nothing Then
    If DicForms.ContainsKey(formName) Then
        Dim fmr As New Form
        fmr = DicForms.Item(formName)
        OpenForm(DicForms.Item(formName))
    End If
End If
```

If a form is opening for first time, it'll show. But when opening the same form, for example when I try to open `FrmAbout` for first time, it'll show but for the second time, I'm getting an error:

`Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'FrmAbout'`

What I've done so far:

```
If Not formName Is Nothing Then
    If DicForms.ContainsKey(formName) Then
        Dim frm As New Form
        frm = DicForms.Item(formName)
        OpenForm(DicForms.Item(formName))
    End If
End If
```

But this doesn't working as I expected : it's showing the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

One: create a new instance of the form when you want to show it. Don't create a dictionary of `String, Form`, but `String, Type`, and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a fresh instance every time:

```
If Not formName Is Nothing Then
    If DicForms.ContainsKey(formName) Then
       Dim fmrType = DicForms.Item(formName)
        Dim frm = Directcast(Activator.CreateInstance(fmrType), Form)
        OpenForm(frm)
    End If
End If
```

Two: Handle the closing event of your forms, and hide them instead of closing them. This way, you can show them again, because they won't get disposed.

Comment: @gabriele You should pass a type to that dictionary, so use `DicForms.Add("FrmAbout", GetType(Medlabsi9.FrmAbout))`

Comment: @gabriele Depends on what your forms look like. Are they rather lightweight and is creation fast? Then you shouldn't have problems. If, OTOH, creation takes a lot of time or you want to cache data that you store in the forms themself, you could use option two.

Comment: Most of the forms are generating fast and my project is  still under development

Comment: BTW, Is there any performance difference between hiding a form vs. show again and. closing a form and show again ??

Comment: @gabriele hiding/showing should be faster, but if your forms are lightweight, it shouldn't really matter